# How to copy laravel 5 project on my server

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to copy laravel 5 project on my server without installing it 
E.g : host it with ftp then trying to run it without anything ??
If that's not possible can I somehow copy the laravel 5 project without 
installing it , because i don't want to use ssh on my cpanel and Thank :)

Comment: Did you install it locally and set the directory permissions as needed? If so then yes, you can simply FTP everything up as is.

Comment: I install it locally but when Ftp everything the index page show nothing !!

Comment: Then you'll need to setup the proper document root and also make sure that things like apache2 rewrite is installed along with mcrypt.

Comment: I would like to see a way for just copying it or something without installing

Comment: what @ChristopherPecoraro means is, you do not need to install laravel or composer, but of course the server-prerequsites must be installed, such as rewrite and mcrypt. if this is not the case, your app will not run without further effort by simply ftp-ing it up.